# How do I turn Password Protected Sharing on or off programmatically?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

Windows Vista and 7 has this switch in Network and Sharing Center. It's on by default, and that prevents unauthenticated access to shares even if they're shared with Everyone (like the Public folder). I need to teach my application to turn it on and off automagically. How? <s>I suspect there is a value somewhere in the registry that's responsible for this, but I have no idea how to find it.</s>

Comment: Do you want to enable "sharing so that everyone with network access can read and write files in the public folders" found in "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings" on Win7?

Comment: No. I want to enable/disable Password protected sharing. It's the second setting from the bottom.

Answer (score 4):

Probably too late :) , but hopefully useful for others.

The following steps worked just fine for me (it worked on W8 consumer preview too).

to turn it off:

1 - Enable guest account by running

> net user guest /active:yes

2 - Obtain guest user SID by running, for example,

> wmic useraccount where name='guest' get sid

3 - Obtain write access to registry folder HKLM\SECURITY

4 - Modify the following key, where $SID is the sid obtained in point 2, to:

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY\Policy\Accounts\$SID\ActSysAc]
>   @=hex(0):41,00,00,00

5 - restart the machine (until now, I didn't find a better way to make the change effective)

to turn it on again:

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY\Policy\Accounts\$SID\ActSysAc]
>   @=hex(0):c1,00,00,00

then restart

Comment: can you write it on cmd to understand?

Answer (score 1):

Export the complete register as 1.reg, turn sharing on (or off, if it was on), export to 2.reg and check for the differences?

To be able to use the `diff` utility, export the files in `Win9X/NT4 registration files (*.reg)` -format

Comment: The files only show changes in MuiCache and MRUListEx (whatever those are) in HKEY_USERS. Note, the switch I'm looking for is system wide and should be in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

Comment: Ok, so apparently it is not in the reg :(

Comment: @CannibalSmith: MRUListEx is for "most recently used (MRU)" items, so that they'll appear higher in lists that contain things you've recently been using.

Comment: It would be easier to just use Process Monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a powershell script that implements paolos answer. It is unpolished as it permits everybody write access to the specific registry key (The [7] part specifies this with regini syntax) and uses a file in C:\ root but works flawless:

```powershell
# Get guest user id
$SID = & "wmic" "useraccount" "where" "name='guest'" "get" "sid" "/Value" | Out-String
$SID = $SID.Trim().Substring(4)

# Generate regini script
$PATH = "\Registry\Machine\Security\Policy\Accounts\" + $SID + "\ActSysAc"
$PATH + " [7]`r`n" + $PATH + "`r`n@ = REG_NONE 4 0x41 0x00 0x00 0x00" >> "C:\firstrun.regini"

# Execute regini script
& "regini" "C:\firstrun.regini"
```

Comment: Works spot on - on Windows Server 2016.  Requires a restart to enable though.

Answer (score 0):

It is in the registry just not necessarily in the place you are expecting (it is in the SAM). From what I can tell all that setting does is enable or disable the guest account, so, well, just enable or disable the account.

You didn't say what you programming language you are using, so here is some simple C code to enable an account, if you need anything else I am sure there is plenty around via google.

```
#include <LM.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Netapi32.lib")

BOOL EnableUser(LPCWSTR lpUserName, BOOL bEnable)
{
    BOOL bRet = FALSE;
    DWORD dwLevel = 1008;
    LPUSER_INFO_1 ui1;
    USER_INFO_1008 ui1008;
    NET_API_STATUS nStatus;

    nStatus = NetUserGetInfo(NULL, lpUserName, 1, (LPBYTE*)&ui1);
    if(nStatus == NERR_Success)
    {
        ui1008.usri1008_flags = ui1->usri1_flags;
        if(bEnable)
        {
            ui1008.usri1008_flags &= ~UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE;
        }
        else
        {
            ui1008.usri1008_flags |= UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE;
        }

        nStatus = NetUserSetInfo(NULL, lpUserName,  dwLevel, (LPBYTE)&ui1008, NULL);
        NetApiBufferFree(ui1);
        if(nStatus == NERR_Success)
        {
            bRet = TRUE;
        }   
    }

    return bRet;
}
```

Comment: Your code neither disables Password Protected Sharing nor enables the Guest account. I stepped through it to make sure all API calls return 0. Also, enabling the Guest account manually through Control Panel doesn't affect Password Protected Sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this file (disable_password_protected_sharing.bat)

```
@echo off
echo 12- get sid gust variable
for /f "delims= " %%a in ('"wmic useraccount where name='guest' get sid"') do (
       if not "%%a"=="SID" (          
          set sid_guest=%%a
          goto :loop_end
       )   
    )

:loop_end

echo 13- create script for regini
@echo \Registry\Machine\SECURITY [1 5 7 11 17 21]> x
@echo \Registry\Machine\SECURITY\policy [1 5 7 11 17 21]>> x
@echo \Registry\Machine\SECURITY\policy\accounts [1 5 7 11 17 21]>> x
@echo \Registry\Machine\SECURITY\policy\accounts\%sid_guest% [1 5 7 11 17 21]>> x
@echo \Registry\Machine\SECURITY\policy\accounts\%sid_guest%\ActSysAc [1 5 7 11 17 21]>> x

echo 14- add permission for machine/security
net user guest /active:yes
regini x
del x
@echo Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 > y.reg
@echo [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY\Policy\Accounts\%sid_guest%\ActSysAc] >> y.reg
@echo @=hex(0):41,00,00,00 >> y.reg
reg import y.reg
del y.reg

echo Windows will now reboot.
Pause

shutdown -r
```

it works fine in windows7

Answer (score 0):

I tested Paolo's answer on windows 7 Home without success.
Comparing the `.reg` extraction of the registry before and after turning off the password protected sharing, I noticed modifications in 3 values:

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY\Policy\Accounts\S-1-5-21-3207962671-1026919178-1165869658-501\ActSysAc] REG_NONE` value's first byte changed from `c1` to `41` (this SID is the guest account's SID)

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY\SAM\Domains\Account] REG_BINARY "F"` value's 17th byte changed from `3b` to `3c`

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY\SAM\Domains\Account\Users\000001F5] REG_BINARY "F"` value's 57th byte changed from `15` to `14` (`0x1F5` is the type of the guest's Names value)

I tried changing only the first value as indicated by Paolo. This did not change the password protected sharing even after reboot.
But I had success when changing the 57th byte between `14` and `15` only for the third value:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY\SAM\Domains\Account\Users\000001F5] REG_BINARY "F".
```

I tested with success on another windows 7 computer.